# Rewrite Module not Working

Tags: apache

I installed last night wamp on my win 7 laptop and started creating a small framework for my projects,

But when I firstly added the RewriteEngine on,it just wasn't working. So I checked to see if the module was on, After I edited the conf file and restarted the server and also checked on apache mods under wamp menu, i confirmed that it was on. So i try to check the page again and I still get an internal server error. So i check the conf file again to check directories permission settup and it seems fine.

So then I go go the error logs and I find `Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`. I checked if the .so file actually exist. I dont know what else to try, please help me before i go nuts.

```
<Directory >
AllowOverride none
Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
AllowOverride All
Allow From All
Require all granted
</Directory> 

#LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it didn't make sense to me why the RewriteEngine wasn't working (code wise). I suspect there was something wrong with my Wamp installation (it would work in the background even after I close it) even though it was a fresh installation. So I decided to re-install the Wamp server, change the Apache conf file and everything is working fine now.